# How To Make Iris Color Picker Showed Up Over Form and Text?

Tags: admin, jquery-ui, color-picker

Is there a way to make wordpress default color picker (iris) showed up over form and text using wordpress api?

Its inline display messing up the administration page of my plugin each time the color picker box showed up.

Comment: Show the relevant parts of your code.

Comment: Screenshot might be in order as well when dealing with display issues.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer.

SO, there is no need to use wordpress api to make the color picker box showed up over another elemnn/s when the 'Select color' button is clicked.

Just add this css code to your plugin/ theme administration css file:

```
.wp-picker-clear,
div.wp-picker-holder {
z-index: 999 !important;
position: absolute !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[Here's the full documentation on Iris](http://automattic.github.io/Iris/). There you can see that you can set a "target" for where the actual pallette appears with a DOM element.

Here's a sample code:

**Your JS:**

```
$('.color-picker').iris({
target: '#colorpickertarget'
});
```

**Your HTML**

```
<form>
<input class="color-picker" type="text" />
<input type="submit"></form>
<div id="colorpickertarget"></div>
```